# Dynamic Inflated View to determine the position

Tags: android, arraylist, view, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I have dynamically created a `LinearLayout` which contains an `EditText` and one Add Button.

Depending upon the Web Service, the `LinearLayout` may have 2, 3 or etc. buttons.

For the better understanding, let's say I have 3 dynamically inflated `LinearLayouts` with `EditTexts` and an add Button.

Now, I have three web services:

- addData
- getData
- editData

addData Web Service is used to add the data to Web server and when we add we can retrieve the data using getData webservice.
In addData Web Service I am passing the positionIndex of inflated `LinearLayout` with `EditText` text while hitting the Add button and getData with the PositionIndex.

```
[{"truckNo":"truck2_no","driverName":"driver2_name","driverMobile":"driver2_mobile","driverLicense":"driver2_license","placeOfIssue":"place2_of_issue","id":3,"positionIndex":1},{"truckNo":"ggg","driverName":"ggg","driverMobile":"vvh","driverLicense":" vv","placeOfIssue":"vvg","id":4,"positionIndex":3}]
```

If the positionIndex lie on the getData web service then I can edit the data of the corresponding position. This means if positionIndex is 3 then we can edit only position 3 as we can see in the JSON. I can edit position 1 and position 3 inflated `LinearLayout` but for position 2, I have to use addData web service.

**Problem:** 
When I use getData from the web service, I am unable to differentiate which data is editable and which one I have to add according to position.

On hitting add Button code:

```
if(truckDetailList!=null && truckDetailList.size()>0) {
    for(int k=0;k<truckDetailList.size();k++) {
       Log.e("id--->>",""+(view1.getId()+1)+"");
       Log.e("truckDetailList-->>",""+truckDetailList.get(k).getTruck_index_position());

       int getTruckPosition=truckDetailList.get(k).getTruck_index_position();

       if(getTruckPosition==(view1.getId()+1)) {
           //Log.e("",""+truck_nmbr_autocmplt.getText().toString(), driverNames, driverMobiles, driverLicncs, plcOfIssues, truckDetailList.get(view1.getId()).getId(), truck_nmbr_autocmplt, driverName, driverMobile, driverLicnc, plcOfIssue)
           editTruckDetail(truck_nmbr_autocmplt.getText().toString(), driverNames, driverMobiles, driverLicncs, plcOfIssues, truckDetailList.get(k).getId(), truck_nmbr_autocmplt, driverName, driverMobile, driverLicnc, plcOfIssue);
           break;
       }
       else {
           postTruckDetailToServer(truck_nmbr_autocmplt.getText().toString(), driverNames, driverMobiles, driverLicncs, plcOfIssues, subID, supplierResponse, truck_nmbr_autocmplt, driverName, driverMobile, driverLicnc, plcOfIssue, position_index);
           break;
       }
    }
 }
else {
    postTruckDetailToServer(truck_nmbr_autocmplt.getText().toString(), driverNames, driverMobiles, driverLicncs, plcOfIssues, subID, supplierResponse, truck_nmbr_autocmplt, driverName, driverMobile, driverLicnc, plcOfIssue, position_index);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best habit to use List View or Recycler View when this type of requirement comes. It will handle the position automatically so you do not need to manage it manually.